# Дополнительное окно

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Подскажите как сделать такое всплывающее окно в окне браузера, при нажатии на кнопку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всплывающее окно это скрытый блок, который показывается при определенных условиях. Есть куча плагинов, которые позволяют это сделать, например — http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На прикреплённой картинки изображено popup окно. 
Простейший пример модального окна:

**html:**

```
<div class="b-container">
    Sample Text
    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()">Show popup</a>
</div>
<div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        Text in Popup
    <a href="javascript:PopUpHide()">Hide popup</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    font-family: Areal;
}
.b-container{
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    color: #fff;
}
.b-popup{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.b-popup .b-popup-content{
    margin:40px auto 0px auto;
    width:100px;
    height: 40px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    PopUpHide();
});
function PopUpShow(){
    $("#popup1").show();
}
function PopUpHide(){
    $("#popup1").hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7NbX/15/